# Most natural smooth interpolation of 1,4=2^2,3^27,4^4^4^4,

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a functional equation for extending this to a smooth real function?

Comment: It sure seems like a rather silly question. However, a priori one could say the same thing about the sequence of factorials. So I will upvote it, just for kicks...

Comment: Silly or not it has a Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration

Comment: Noam D. Elkies : interesting page, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
f(x,y)=x^{f(x,y-1)},
$$
$$
f(x,1)=x.
$$
Then your function is given by $g(n)=f(n,n)$.